# Unable to locate Font Manager in Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Cannot find Font Manager in Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 under Tools Menu as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj171003(v=vs.110).aspx).

Any idea where I can find it in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Font Manager you refer to is for **Blend**, not for Visual Studio.